# Sending multiple form datePicker data to the same destinations

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm having issues with creating multiple unique datepicker instances within one div and then submitting the dates in a form.

My issue is that my div currently has multiple array elements building this form:

```
<?php foreach($expiredPages as $expiredPage): ?>
<form id="updateTime_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" class="updateTime" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currentPageID" value="<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>">
                    <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" data-target-input="nearest">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" name="datePicker<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
  <input type="submit" name="Extend Date" class="extendDate">
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

WHich means I have 3 forms in the div, each with its own datepicker and submit button. I've fixed this to make sure each datepicker works independently, but I can't figure out how to uniquely pass my two inputs to the PHP.

I'm getting errors of undefined index for both currentPageID and datePicker

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".extendDate").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var string = $('.updateTime').serialize();
            console.log(string);

              // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "extendTime.php",
                      data: string,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(response){
                        location.reload();
               }
           });
       });
  </script>
```

extendTime.php

```
$pageID = $_POST['currentPageID'];
$dtPick = 'datePicker' . $pageID;
$newTime = $_POST[$dtPick];

$newEndTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i A', $newTime);
$convertedDateTime = $newEndTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$extendExpiration = "
  UPDATE pages 
  SET end_time = '$convertedDateTime'
  WHERE id = '$pageID';
";

if($mysqlConn->query($extendExpiration)=== TRUE){
  echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
  echo "Could not extend Time";
}
```

Comment: Seems like a selector problem. If you are doing anything that revolves around id's, then those id's will have to be unique, or the logic will only revolve around the fist instance that it finds with said id.

Comment: I think the issue is that in my form my datepicker input name is ```datepicker``` which I've now added an ID to, however, in my php it's just ```datepicker```

Comment: @Martin I've fixed the uniqueness of the datepicker, but I need to figure out how to make the name of my two inputs unique and passed to the PHP that way

Comment: On a quick note, you might want to parse *event* in your function since you're doing an *event.preventDefault();*. Chrome is very forgiving with window events, but browsers like Mozilla Firefox is not.

Comment: If php remains the only issue I would editvthe question a bit...

Comment: I have edited it now

Comment: this must be someones home work, the same question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480388/passing-unique-input-name-into-php-post-variable

Comment: @noid That was actually just an honest mistake. I accidentally logged out of a colleagues account before posting and noticed it when I went to alter the question and repost

Comment: @noid and no it's not homework, it's a pet project I'm working on

Comment: isnt there a loop missing (as in the other post) if you have many instances of the same input name , use an array and put the Id into the array as part of the name

Comment: The loop is in there around the form. I'm just not quite sure how to do that. I can make the name ```datepicker[]``` and put the id within those brackets, but how do I then pass that name in the POST of the php script?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your php, you don't have  post key called datePicker...

```
$_POST['datePicker'];
```

doesn't exists... 
you add to your input's name an id:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker_<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" name="datePicker<?php echo $expiredPage['id']?>" />
```

A simple fix should be something like this :

```
$dtpick = 'datePicker' . $pageID;
      $newTime  = $_POST[$dtpick];
```

Comment: Personally I would have the php the same in any case. 
But to do that I would recommend working in MVC

Comment: this is giving me an array to string conversion error at the ```$newTime``` line and showing it as datePickerArray (as opposed to datePicker123)

Comment: strange... I'll try a minor fix to the answer

Comment: I've converted it to use the class of the form too and so it submits for each form even if I only click one submit button

Comment: I've edited my question to my newest code. The edit you made still gives me an array to string conversion. My previous comment was just stating that I had the formID as the data to be serialized but I realized that wouldn't work because it wasn't unique

Comment: Good point. I changed that back and it did pass the error, but it fails on my format() method saying that it can't call that on boolean

Comment: Yes, it's updated. I only changed the currentPageID input

Comment: That's been there the whole time in my extendTime.php file ```$convertedDateTime = $newEndTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');```  It formats the date and time from the datepicker. But it's calling that on a boolean so it's not passing the data properly

Comment: that's an error one line above... meaning the data received in the ajax was not properly formatted

Comment: I guess that's my issue. All of my existing code works in another page that uses only one form with one datetimepicker. The only issue here is that I'm trying to pass that data based on multiple instances. The other page formats the datetimepicker value from the same ajax serialize call. But because it's now getting an array, it sees boolean rather than a value. I'll just have to keep messing with the unique aspect of this. Thanks for your help though